# On Import, where is county field?

Tags: import, 4.6.10, fields, county, field-mapping

I've noticed upon matching mapping fields in the import process that for some fields in the file they are missing in the CiviCRM drop-downs. For instance, for a field named "Home County' the CiviCRM drop-down for 'County does not appear. But choose 'Employee of' and 'County' appears. In fact, it is one of the only other, unrelated fields that it appears.

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is 'State' there? The two are synonymous afaik.

Comment: No, state and county are distinct--a county is a subdivision of a state in some countries.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is almost certainly that the "County" field is not enabled by default, which suppresses it in the import dialog.

Go to **Administer menu > Localization > Address Settings**, and under "Address Editing", see if the "County" box is checked.  If not, check it.  Restart your import and the field should appear.

I also confirmed your report that County appears even if disabled as a field for related contacts.  That's a bug, though a very low priority one!

Comment: An additional note: once you check the county box, you'll find that you have only five counties.  (Because loading the entire world's counties would be overwhelming, CiviCRM just ships with a handful.)  If you're in the US, go to Administer > System Settings > Manage Extensions, then the Add New tab, and click Download next to the US County Loader.  On a Drupal site, this would be at example.org/civicrm/admin/extensions?action=update&id=com.aghstrategies.uscounties&key=com.aghstrategies.uscounties

Comment: Just checked and county is set to be an importable field (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/xml/schema/Core/Address.xml#L268).

Comment: @JoeMurray - it IS importable per the schema, but like other address fields, if it's disabled in the location I mentioned above, it will not appear in the list of importable fields in the import UI.

Answer (score 0):

Check the country field is there for which (contact, events, etc.) you are trying to import or not. Suppose you are trying to import contact then you need to check the country field is there or not for contact (you can check it by creating a new contact link). If there is no country field, then you need to add a custom field for contact.